# Kentico: Unpublish all children of folder in CMSDesk

Tags: kentico

How do I unpublish all children of a folder or a tree node in the CMSDesk in Kentico 8.1

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the node
2. Switch to "Listing" (above the tree)
3. Select child documents you want to unpublish
4. In the dropdown list below the grid, select "Archive"
5. Click OK and select whether you want to apply the action also to child nodes

That's the only way to do it via UI.